# Front-End Social photo upload

Tags: uploads, woocommerce-offtopic, front-end, social-connect

I’m looking for a plugin which helps me to add image uploader on front-end of my website for my woocommerce customers and then review uploaded photo by admin and if accepted they will be added on home page or somewhere in page block. it will be very good if such plugin has not only uploading from computer, but upload from facebook and instagram. Thank you very much!